# Homework: electrical circuit with 2 voltage sources & 1 switch

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I can't figure out how to handle this circuit. I am asked to calculate the total resistance and the current over each resistance (R1-R4) when the **switch is open**. However I'm not getting anywhere because I can't figure out the following points:

- Does the voltage source in the middle (above R4) force the voltage on the node between R1 and R4 back to 5V?
- Or what influence (if any) does the voltage source above R4 have on the circuit when the **switch is open**?
- Does the current coming from R1 divide at the first node so that one part goes towards the second voltage source (above R4) and the other part towards R2 when the **switch** is **open**?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: current *through*, voltage *across/over* :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the very functioning of an open switch, there can be no current through the switch, and there is no constraint on the voltage across the terminals of the switch.

This of course means that there cannot be a current through the entire branch containing R4 (and therefore the resistance R4 plays no role in this case). The current then flows through the rest of the circuit as if the branch did not exist.

Consequentially, the only effect of the voltage source in this branch is to maintain a potential difference between the node at its positive terminal and the negative terminal, showing up as a measurable voltage across the switch (with a value different from what you would have if the voltage source were not there). This does not affect the voltage at the node between R1 and R2, as that is determined by the current through them, which (as pointed out previously) is completely independent of the existence of the branch containing R4.